# Unilateral Laplace transform

Tags: laplace-transform

I tried to do the same unilateral Laplace transform in two ways, but I got different results. I have to calculate: $\mathcal{L}[r(t-1)]$, where $r(t)$ is the ramp function, that is $r(t)=t, t\ge0$.

$1^{st}$  way: $\mathcal{L}[r(t-1)]=\mathcal{L}[t-1]=\mathcal{L}[t]-\mathcal{L}[u(t)]=\frac{1}{s^2}-\frac{1}{s}$, where $u(t)$ is the unit step function.

$2^{nd}$ way (using Laplace transform properties): $\mathcal{L}[r(t-1)]=\mathcal{L}[t-1]=e^{-s}\frac{1}{s^2}=\frac{1}{e^s s^2}$

What's wrong with the second way? Is it right?

Comment: Neither solution is correct.  Recall that from the definition of $r$, $r(t-1)=(t-1)u(t-1)=t-1$ for $t\ge 1$ and zero elsewhere.  Thus, one writes $\mathscr{L}\{r(t-1)\}=e^{-s}\mathscr{L}\{(t)\}\ne \mathscr{L}\{(t-1)\}$.  Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I just want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: I understand my error. Thank you for this precisation too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Laplace Transform of $r(t-1)$ is

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{L}\{r(t-1)\}(s)&=\int_0^{\infty}r(t-1)e^{-st}dt\\\\
&=\int_0^{\infty}(t-1)u(t-1)e^{-st}dt\\\\
&=\int_1^{\infty}(t-1)e^{-st}dt \tag1\\\\
&=e^{-s}\int_0^{\infty}te^{-st}dt \tag 2\\\\
&=e^{-s}\mathscr{L}\{r(t)\}(s)\\\\
&=e^{-s}\frac1{s^2}
\end{align}$$

In going from $(1)$ to $(2)$, we used the substitution $t-1 \to t$.  Then, $e^{-st}\to e^{-s(t+1)}=e^{-s}e^{-st}$ and the new integration limits begin at $0$.

Comment: since the $\mathcal{L}[r(t)]=\mathcal{L}[t]=\frac{1}{s^2}$, shouldn't it be $\mathcal{L}[r(t-1)]=e^{-s}\frac{1}{s^2}$?

Comment: also: I didn't understand this passage $\int_1^{\infty}(t-1)e^{-st}dt=e^{-s}\int_0^{\infty}te^{-st}dt$. Could you kindly explain-me this?

Comment: @sleax Yes, you are correct.  Edited.  And I added explanation that you requested.  Please let me know how I can improve further.

Comment: I can't really understand that passage. Why $t-1\rightarrow t$ ? I thought to do $t-1=r$, so it becomes $e^{-s }\int_{1'}^{\infty} r e^{-sr} dr$.

Comment: @sleax Note that $r$ is just a "dummy" variable and one could change it to $t$ or $x$ or any other label.  So, I used $t$.  Does that make sense?

Comment: So I wrote the same thing as you did. It's just a question of naming. Also: the lower bound of integration changes from 1 to 0 because in $(1) $ with $t=1$ the integral goes to zero and the same thing in $(2)$ is done with $t=0$. Right?

Comment: @sleax You have it now!  Well done.

Answer (score 1):

Both of your methods of computing $\mathcal{L}[r(t-1)u(t-1)]$ will work, but your 1st method needs fixing.

- 1st way (Linearity): You tried to write $\mathcal{L}[r(t-1)]=\mathcal{L}[t-1]=\mathcal{L}[t]-\mathcal{L}[u(t)]=\frac{1}{s^2}-\frac{1}{s}$.
  This is wrong because $r(t-1)u(t-1)\neq t - u(t)$.

To fix this, use the correct expression $r(t-1)u(t-1) = t - g(t)$, where 
$$g(t) = \begin{cases} t,& 0\leq t\leq 1 \\ 1 ,& t\geq 1\end{cases}$$
(You can see that $g(t)$ is equal to $u(t)$, except for the part between $0\leq t\leq 1$.)
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}[r(t-1)u(t-1)] 
&= \mathcal{L}[t] - \mathcal{L}[g(t)]\\
&= \frac{1}{s^2} - \frac{1}{s^2}(1 - e^{-s}) \\
&= e^{-s}\frac{1}{s^2}
\end{align}
This way (using Linearity) works, but is not as easy as using the Time Shifting Property, because the Laplace transform of $g(t)$ is more difficult to compute.

- 2nd way (Time Shifting): Easier method.  You used the Time Shift Property correctly.
  $$\mathcal{L}[r(t-1)u(t-1)] = e^{-s}\mathcal{L}[r(t)] = e^{-s}\frac{1}{s^2}$$